# Append a digit at the beginning of character data using stringr or gsub

Tags: r, string, gsub

I have one data sets with name `DATA_TEST`.This data frame contain 6-observations in character format.You can see table below.

```r
dput(DATA_TEST)
structure(list(Ten_digits = c("NA", "207", "0101", "0208 90", 
"0206 90 99 00", "103")), .Names = "Ten_digits", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# > DATA_TEST
#       Ten_digits
# 1            NA
# 2           207
# 3          0101
# 4       0208 90
# 5 0206 90 99 00
# 6           103
```

So my intention is to convert this data frame with a stringr or other package like picture below. Actually the code needs to do one thing or more precisely
first must found only variables with three digits like `207` or `103` and convert this variables into `0207` and `0103`.
In the table below you can see finally what the table should look like.

```r
# > Desired Output
#       Ten_digits
# 1            NA
# 2          0207
# 3          0101
# 4       0208 90
# 5 0206 90 99 00
# 6          0103
```

So can anybody help me with this code ?

Comment: Are there values like `234 45 56` that need to be converted to `0234 45 56`?

Comment: Ok, seems like `DATA_TEST$Ten_digits <- sub("^(\\d{3})$", "0\\1", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits, perl=TRUE)` would also do.

Comment: No, only values with three digits like 207.You can see on second table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_length` from `stringr`:

```
library(tidyverse) # in order to load all required packages at once

DATA_TEST %>% 
  mutate(Ten_digits = case_when(
    str_length(Ten_digits) == 3 ~ paste0("0", Ten_digits),
    TRUE ~ Ten_digits
    ))

# Ten_digits
#1            NA
#2          0207
#3          0101
#4       0208 90
#5 0206 90 99 00
#6          0103
```

`str_length` allows you to vectorize lengths of your character vector: from the [function's documentation](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_length.html):

> `Technically this returns the number of "code points", in a string. One code point usually corresponds to one character(...)`.

`case_when` allows to vectorize multiple `if_else` statements.

As mentioned in comments, you can use `ifelse` or `if_else`, which are more straightforward than `case_when`. See example below inside the microbenchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  DATA_TEST %>% 
    mutate(Ten_digits = case_when(
      str_length(Ten_digits) == 3 ~ paste0("0", Ten_digits),
      TRUE ~ Ten_digits
    )),
  DATA_TEST %>% 
    mutate(Ten_digits = ifelse(
      str_length(Ten_digits) == 3, paste0("0", Ten_digits),
      Ten_digits
    )),
  DATA_TEST %>% 
    mutate(Ten_digits = if_else(
      str_length(Ten_digits) == 3, paste0("0", Ten_digits),
      Ten_digits
    ))
)

#     min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
# 785.809 806.9130 1051.9314 858.217 1193.865 2445.434   100  # case_when
# 613.398 623.3985  862.6720 636.858  822.027 8610.763   100  # ifelse
# 625.485 641.1370  822.3502 664.135  894.812 1995.932   100  # if_else
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It does exactly the OP asks using the package it asks for.

Comment: Maybe I'm not entirely understanding the problem. Are you expecting there to be more conditions to test? If not, `ifelse`/`if_else` would be shorter and more straightforward

Comment: I answered the OP just how it was asked. You can do the same thing in different ways, but this is no reason for downvoting. If you hover over downvoting you will see `this answer is not useful`, which it clearly does. Anyways, I edited my post.

Comment: I actually upvoted it. I think it's a good answer; if I could upvote a second time now that you added benchmarks, I would. I really just meant the question that I asked about whether you were leaving space for scaling to more conditions

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple regex with `sub`:

```
DATA_TEST<-data.frame(Ten_digits=c("NA","207","0101","0208 90","0206 90 99 00","103"),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
DATA_TEST$Ten_digits <- sub("^(\\d{3})$", "0\\1", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits)
DATA_TEST
## => Ten_digits
1            NA
2          0207
3          0101
4       0208 90
5 0206 90 99 00
6          0103
```

Here, `^(\\d{3})$` matches a three digit string and captures the digits into Group 1 (since the pattern is inside parentheses) and the `0\1` replacement pattern inserts a `0` and adds back the whole match value in Group 1.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this simply by pasting a `0` in front of 3-char strings, i.e.

```
DATA_TEST$Ten_digits[nchar(DATA_TEST$Ten_digits) == 3] <- paste0("0", DATA_TEST$Ten_digits[nchar(DATA_TEST$Ten_digits) == 3])
DATA_TEST

#     Ten_digits
#1            NA
#2          0207
#3          0101
#4       0208 90
#5 0206 90 99 00
#6          0103
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_pad` from `stingr`. Note that it'll pad any string with length less than 4 characters so the code will need modification if you specifically want to focus on strings with length 3. Also `ifelse` won't be needed if you had a literal `NA` instead of "NA". -

```
DATA_TEST %>% 
  mutate(
    Ten_digits = ifelse(Ten_digits == "NA", "NA", str_pad(Ten_digits, width = 4, pad = 0))
  )

     Ten_digits
1            NA
2          0207
3          0101
4       0208 90
5 0206 90 99 00
6          0103
```